# How do I remove the parentheses in each cell of the csv file when using csv.writer?

Tags: python, list, csv, parentheses, writer

I am trying to write export a csv file that contains some numbers. This is my code

```
def exportROI_spectra_val_Callback(self):
    img_mean = self.ROI_img_mean[self.ROI_listselect_text]
    # export_dat = np.vstack([self.z, img_mean]).T
    path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save CSV', os.getenv('HOME'), 'CSV(*.csv)')
    if path[0] != '':
        with open(path[0], 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect='excel', delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
            for row in range (len(self.z)):
                row_data = []
                row_data.append((self.z[row],img_mean[row]))
                writer.writerow(row_data)
```

The result that I am expecting in my .csv file is having 2 columns with each cell just having a single number like this.

```
     A       B
1 99.84281   0
2 99.84854   0
3 99.85427   0
4 99.85999   0
5 100.0032 468.65
```

But what I actually get is the numbers with parentheses in each cell like this.

```
      A         B
1 (99.84281     0)
2 (99.84854     0)
3 (99.85427     0)
4 (99.85999     0)
5 (100.0032  468.65)
```

How do I remove the parentheses and only have the numbers so that I can use them for further computation in excel?

Comment: Make a [mcve].  This isn't complete code that reproduces the issue.  Show what the .csv text file contains, not what the pandas dataframe looks like.  Show input data and output result.  If there are parentheses in the columns, there were parentheses in the `row_data` that you haven't shown.

Comment: You're appending a tuple to every row `row_data.append((self.z[row],img_mean[row]))` you need to add each value individually. All you have to do to debug yourself this is (was) print the row or the value being appended, it would appear in ( ) which should have pointed you at the problem.